# VUE.JS - How to use a class that is outside of vue.js in the javascript file of vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, export, require

I'm using vue.js to create a webpage, and I'm trying to use a class (Authenticator) that is outside of my two files (Login.html and Login.js) that are using vue.js. **But I can't seem to manage to import that class (Authenticator) in my Login.js file to use it's function...**

Is there a way to do that? Here is my code:

**Login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body class="background">
    <div class="border">

        <div id="app">
            [...]
        </div> <!--  End of app -->

    </div> <!--  End of border -->

    <script src="./vue.js"></script>
    <script src="./Login.js"></script>
    <script src="../controller/Authenticator.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Login.js**

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        username: null,
        password: null,
        activeUsers: []
    },

    methods: {
        verifyLogin: function () {

            // Verify if fields have been filled
            if (null === this.username || null === this.password) {

                window.alert("Error, please fill out the form correctly!");

            } else {
                // If fields are filled, verify the authentication

                var authenticator = new Authenticator(this.username);    
                var authenticated = authenticator.authenticateUser(this.username, this.password);

                [...]

                } else if (null === authenticated) {
                    // Error, if authentication failed
                    window.alert("Wrong password, please try again!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Authenticator.js**

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://192.168.99.100:27017/UserDB";
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt'); // Hash algorithm
const saltRounds = 10;

export default class Authenticator {
    constructor(iNewUserName) {
        this.mActiveUserNames.push(iNewUserName);
    }

    async authenticateUser(iUserName, iPassword) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

I get the error **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'"** on the webpage console. Also, I tried to change the method of exporting by doing:

```
module.exports = Authenticator;
```

But then I get the error **"Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at Authenticator.js:2"** from the webpage console.

Can someone help me please, I looked everywhere online, and I cannot find the solution?

Thank you.

Comment: At least you must to load Authenticator.js before Login.js. Becouse Login.js used class from Authenticator.js

Comment: Hey, do you mean in the Login.html file where the scipts are?

Comment: Yes, try to change order

Comment: Ok, I just did, but it still have the same problem.